# For/In Loop is spitting out random numbers, as opposed to what I'd assume

Tags: javascript, minecraft

I am new to coding, and this has really got me questioning things...

I'll post a bit of the code, including the enum that I use and what I assume it should be saying.
My Enum:

```
var schedule = {
    CommuteWork: {
            time: [1],
            action: function() {npc.say("Hello!");}    
        },
    Work: {
            time: [2,3,4,5,6],
            action: function() {}
        },
    CommuteHome: {
            time: [7],
            action: function() {}
        },
    Sleep: {
            time: [8,9,10],
            action: function() {}
        },

    Leisure: {
            time: [5,6,7],
            activities: {
                bar: function() {

                }
            }
        }
}
```

And the code that it is called by:

```
for (act in schedule) {
   npc.say(act);
   for (prop in act) {
       npc.say(prop);
   }
}
```

So, with the npc saying 'act in schedule', he spits out: "CommuteWork" "Work" ect.
What I'd assume this to be doing is: "time" "action".
But for one reason or another, it is giving out: "Leisure" "0" "1" "2" and so on up to 6. 
All of the numbers are different. For example when it says sleep, the numbers are 0 to 4. These numbers don't match prop.time. And they don't match any code I've written. I must've made an error somewhere, but I'm either too tired or don't know enough to see it. I would love some help and an explanation on this, if anyone knows.

Note for those of you who know custom npcs: Yes, the var schedule is declared in init, and I save it under npc.setTempData("schedule", schedule) and call it under update with 'schedule = npc.getTempData("schedule")'. I'm glad to answer questions on it, but I think it's set up correctly.

Comment: `What I'd assume this to be doing is: "time" "action"` - why would you assume that, your code does not do that

Comment: I see what it's doing ... `for( x in "some string")` will have x = 0 ... length of string - 1 .. because `act` is the string `Leisure` ... as you can see because that's what it's output! you need `for (prop in schedule[act])`

Comment: I'd assume this based on the fact that the line just above it 'npc.say(act)' is giving "leisure" and so on. Am I incorrect? Because it is just doing the same thing as that, is it not?

Comment: think to yourself, what is `act` ... is it the name of the property, or the property itself? and those numbers would be sequential ... hardly random, correct?

Comment: Oh alright. Thanks a lot. This really had me frustrated. I'll give it a go really quickly!

Comment: I know this is a stupid question, that I should know by now, but how exactly can I get the name of the property? I haven't done a bit of coding in a while and I've never really been fluent, but someday hopefully.

Comment: you have the name of the properties in `act` and `prop` .. the code you posted, `prop` will be 0 ... length of (act) - 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jaromanda X pointed out in the comments, what was happening was that it was iterating through the string of act, and giving the number. I needed to use `for (prop in schedule[act])` instead of `for (prop in act)`.